# Not able to connect to SQL Server database on AWS linux from another instance of ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I have hosted SQL Server on an AWS linux server. I have hosted an ASP.NET Core Web API on another newly created AWS account.

In Web API, I have used the ip address and password of SQL Server hosted on linux.

But I can not connect when I try to run API in URL and I get error

> Error retrieving data from the database

I have not added database instance nor installed any database-related instance on aws server.

All this is working fine in .NET Core hosted on local IIS.

I tried to follow all the possible articles related to this on aws official website but unable to fund the same and unable to get the answer.

I am also confused that if I want to connect to DB from API then do I needs to install the same or create the db instance? assuming that all required software are pre-installed

Comment: Have you configured the security group of the EC2 instance hosting the SQL server to allow traffic from the security group used by the web API's EC2?

Comment: Yes I have added all ports to be allowed by mentioning in Security group!

Comment: Could you share the rule in the question bro?

Comment: Yes Sure:

Please find the image link below:
https://postimg.cc/dZm243k3

Comment: Make sure SQL Server instance is configured to allow remote connections.On the Linux server, check if the firewall is allowing connections on the SQL Server port.Investigate any AWS-specific networking configurations that might be blocking the connection.Verify that the user account used in the connection string has the necessary permissions on the SQL Server database.Try using a database management tool to connect to your SQL Server from the AWS instance hosting your ASP.NET Core application.This can help isolate whether the issue is with the application or the network/database configuration.

Comment: Thanks @JalpaPanchal for the Reply, I am trying to allow port in Firewall in linux but can you share any specific Command/s to do this ?

Comment: Could you try this command `netstat -na | grep :80
ss -na | grep :80`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, grep: ss: No such file or directory
Also Just want to ask you that 
Sql server DB is hosted on AWS ec2 instance

API is hosted on another AWS ec2 instance

So to connect Remote DB from API project, Do I needs to install some SQL related libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configuration of your security group,

1. You have not opened the ports required by SQL server for the web APIs to be able to access to it.
2. To solve this, you will have to add a TCP/IP (1433) rule and UDP rule (1434) that allows inbound connection to the security group of the SQL server and whitelist the security group of the EC2 hosting the web API.
3. You may wanna consider implementing the least privilege principle and not whitelist everything on the internet to your RDS. You can do this by limiting the IP address range listed on your RDP rule.

Comment: Thank for the Reply.

I have allowed ALL TRAFFIC and also added mssql rule in the inbound rules.
But still getting error.

I have also checked this Remote IP of SQL SERVER in another LAPTOP which has SQL Server Management studio and I'm able to connect it.

So I feels that some configuration like firewall allow port needs to be configured.

Also as a add on, I have Configured nginx server using which I am able to connect to Static url of Web Api but api/controller which has DB connection is still showing this same error.

Comment: Hello @AllanChua, I have added ALL TRAFFIC rule in INBOUND rule and still no luck!